# DirectoryEntry from LDAP or from WinNT. How can I know it?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm developing a C# .NET Framework 4.0 library and I want to know if a `DirectoryEntry` is from `LDAP` or from a local machine. How can I know that?

On `DirectoryEntry` there is a property called Path that starts with "LDAP" or "WinNT". Is this the only way to know it?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the property [Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.options(v=vs.110).aspx) and then call [GetCurrentServerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentryconfiguration.getcurrentservername(v=vs.110).aspx) and compare that with Environment.MachineName?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but Options is null.

Comment: Hmm, too bad...it looked so nice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.rlmueller.net/Name_Attributes.htm) is a good page from Richard Mueller that lists/compares common attributes for WinNT and LDAP objects.  I would suggest checking for "cn" or "samaccountname" attributes if you don't want to string match the path.